# Processor features available

Tags: hardware

What is the processor feature "java" shown below? Is it like an instruction set? How to get use of it?

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2708
Revision        : 000f
Serial          : x
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It might be Jazelle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in comments by Lord Loh, it is [Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazelle) instruction set. It implements subset of java bytcodes as another ARM execution state (besides native one and Thumb). But you can't really use directly it since the documentation published by ARM is not complete and they seem to provide better one only to JVM developers.